# Sending e-mail with php

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send mail from my site.But its not working now. Can you please tell what all changes should I make in `php.ini` configuration file for achieving this functionality? Using windows OS. Here is my code for your reference.

```
     $to = "name@gmail.com";
     $subject = $subject;
     $body = $message;
     if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
           echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
     } else {
           echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
       }
```

Comment: What's $subject and $message?

Comment: subject and message shouldn't matter

Answer (score 2):

Windows doesn't contain an sendmail like Linux does.

So for Windows you have to provide an SMTP server: http://www.geeklog.net/faqman/index.php?op=view&t=19

Answer (score 1):

There may be a lot of things wrong, but for starters, [the PHP manual for `mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) says:

> When sending mail, the mail must contain a From header. This can be set with the additional_headers parameter, or a default can be set in php.ini.
>
> Failing to do this will result in an error message similar to Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing.

You're not setting the `From` header in your code, so that would be the first thing to check.

(Also: `$subject = $subject;` is odd.)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting these as well.

```
           $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
           phpini_set("sendmail_from", "info@mydomain.com"); // at the beginning of yoru script
```